# How to override \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException magento 2

Tags: no-such-entity-exception

I'm tryng to debug a "No such entity exception" error during the creation of a Credit Memo. I want to have a more explicit error message. I work in a Magento Cloud enviroment, so I can't modify the /vendor files.

I've created a new module to override a core method. The module has this path /app/code/Dev/Debug

Here are my files

/app/code/Dev/Debug/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dev_Debug" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

/app/code/Dev/Debug/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException" type="Dev\Debug\Exception\NoSuchEntityExceptionDebug" />
</config>
```

Then my override

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Debug\Exception;

use Magento\Framework\Phrase;

class NoSuchEntityExceptionDebug extends \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
{
    public function __construct(Phrase $phrase = null, \Exception $cause = null, $code = 0)
    {
        $debug = "";
        foreach (debug_backtrace() as $_stack) {
            $debug .= ($_stack["file"] ? $_stack["file"] : '') . ':' .
                ($_stack["line"] ? $_stack["line"] : '') . ' - ' .
                ($_stack["function"] ? $_stack["function"] : '');
        }

        mail("email@gmail.com","DEBUG", $debug);

        exit();


        if ($phrase === null) {
            $phrase = new Phrase('No such entity.');
        }
        parent::__construct($phrase, $cause, $code);
    }
}
```

So, I expect than when the error is raised, the system should send me an e-mail with the debug trace info. But nothing happens.

Can you see any error in my code?

Is it correct to adopt a custom module like mine?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If Override the exception class is not working then you can create a Patch which change directly core file and then you can have your solution in it.

https://magento1544124303.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031695831-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit

I tried your solution but it is not working!

Reason:

- Might be framework classes are being loaded before magento vendor classes.